# How to change maximum waiting threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem with synchronized threads in which I'm using wait() method. It's working fine but after a short moment the program freezes. I've checked number of threads that are in waiting condition and the program is always freezing after reaching 10 waiting threads. Where can I change the maximum waiting threads number so the program won't freeze at any time?

```
public class ThreadTest2 {
    private final static int size = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Account bank = new Account(size,1000);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Transfer t1 = new Transfer(bank, size);
            Thread bankTransfer = new Thread(t1);
            bankTransfer.start();
        }
    }

}

class Account{

    public static int u = 0;
    double[] account;
    int size;
    public Account(int size, double initValue){
        account = new double[size];
        this.size = size;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            account[i] = initValue;
        }
    }

    public synchronized double getTotalBalance(){
        double total = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            total+=account[i];
        return total;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    public double getBalance(int i){
        return account[i];
    }


    public synchronized void transfer(int from, int to, double amount) throws InterruptedException{

        int i = 0;
        if(account[from]<0){ i++; u++;}
            System.out.printf("Account no %d balance: %.2f subtracts %.2f adds to %d\n", from, getBalance(from),amount,to);
            while(account[from]<0)
                wait();
            if(i==1) u--;
            account[from]-=amount;
            System.out.println(" ");
            account[to]+=amount;
            System.out.printf("Total balance: %.2f thread awaiting: %d\n",getTotalBalance(), u);    

            notifyAll();

        }

}

class Transfer implements Runnable{
    Account bank;
    int size;
    public Transfer(Account bank, int size){
        this.bank=bank;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
        try {
            bank.transfer((int)(size * Math.random()), (int)(size * Math.random()), 999*Math.random());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly working code below (thanks to @peter-lawrey).

```
public class ThreadTest2 {
    private final static int size = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Account bank = new Account(size,1000);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Transfer t1 = new Transfer(bank, size);
            Thread bankTransfer = new Thread(t1);
            bankTransfer.start();
        }
    }

}

class Account{

    public static int u = 0;
    double[] account;
    int size;
    boolean[] waiting;
    public Account(int size, double initValue){
        account = new double[size];
        this.size = size;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            account[i] = initValue;
        }
        waiting = new boolean[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            waiting[i] = false;
    }

    public synchronized double getTotalBalance(){
        double total = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            total+=account[i];
        return total;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    public double getBalance(int i){
        return account[i];
    }


    public synchronized void transfer(int from, int to, double amount) throws InterruptedException{
        if(from!=to && waiting[from]!=true){
        int i = 0;
        System.out.printf("Account no %d balance: %.2f subtracts %.2f adds to %d\n", from, getBalance(from),amount,to);
        if(account[from]-amount<0){ i++; u++;}
            while(account[from]-amount<0){
                waiting[from] = true;
                wait();

            }

            if(i==1){ u--; waiting[from] = false;}
            account[from]-=amount;
            System.out.println(" ");
            account[to]+=amount;
            System.out.printf("Total balance: %.2f thread awaiting: %d\n",getTotalBalance(), u);    

            notifyAll();
        }
        }

}

class Transfer implements Runnable{
    Account bank;
    int size;
    public Transfer(Account bank, int size){
        this.bank=bank;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
        try {
            bank.transfer((int)(size * Math.random()), (int)(size * Math.random()), 999*Math.random());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you transfer money around randomly you will have accounts which happen to run out of money.  The longer you run, the more accounts randomly become negative.

The only way to prevent this being a problem is to have as many threads as accounts, because in the worst case there will always be one account with money.

Comment: You're right. Additionally I had to also add a condition that the thread isn't transferring money from an account that is already waiting. Thanks.